# elasticsearch faking index per user - how are routing values inferred when updating?

Tags: elasticsearch

Using the [fake index per user](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/faking-it.html) as suggested by docs. ES version 1.6.0  sometimes fails to behave as expected.

Checking the alias:

```
curl localhost:9200/testbig/_alias/<userId>
{"<indexname>":{"aliases":{"<userId>":{"filter":{"term":  
{"userId":"<userId>"}},"index_routing":"<userId>","search_routing":"<userId>"}}
}}
```

But trying to update a document:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/<userId>/<type>/<id>/_update -d 
'{"doc":{"userId":"<userId>","field1":"val1"}}'
```

I get

```
{ "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Alias [<userId>] has 
index routing associated with it [<userId>], and was provided with 
routing value [<DIFFERENTuserId>], rejecting operation]",
"status": 400 }
```

Comment: Have you enabled routing in mapping and point it to a particular field ?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else suffers a similar issue, what causes is this:

If you start by using actual separate indexes for each user, it's OK to have records with the same id, i.e. paths like

```
localhost:9200/userid1/type/id1
localhost:9200/userid2/type/id1
```

but when the `userids` are just aliases, these correspond, of course, to the same document. Hence the routing clash on subsequent updates.